# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' : Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am unable to **register a user account** in a Laravel project.

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = xxx@xx.com)
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: change your database configuration in `.env` file and give accurate info there

Comment: Make sure that you is update this values in your .env file DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that you update the below values in your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=your_database_name

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=
```

Once updated .env file, stop the server of your project and serve the project again using the `php artisan serve` command.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changes in the **.env** file for the following fields:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= your database name
DB_USERNAME= your user name
DB_PASSWORD= your password
```